# How to build adjacency list from adjacency matrix?

Tags: c, adjacency-list

I have successfully built an adjacency matrix for a input file with the first line of the input as the total number of vertices, and the following lines are edges in arbitrary order as pairs of vertices. eg

**file.txt**

```
7
1 2
4 6
4 3
5 2
```

However, when I run this program, the adjacency matrix is built successfully, but when I try to create an adjacency list as an array of struct tree, the program Seg faults (core dumps). 
Any clue as to why the program fails? The function in question is:

```
tree * buildAdjList(int a[][100], int n)
{       int i, j, k;
    tree *node;
    tree * adjArray[n];
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
            adjArray[i] = NULL;
    for(j=0; j<=n; j++)
            for(k=0; k<=n; k++)
                    if(a[j][k] == 1){
                            node = (tree *)malloc(sizeof(tree));
                            node->val = k;
                            node->next = adjArray[j];
                            adjArray[j] = node;
                    }
    return adjArray[0];
}
```

and the rest of the program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct tree{
    int val;
    struct tree *next;
};

typedef struct tree tree;

void printArray(int a[][100],int n);
void adjacencyMatrix(int a[][100], int n, int p1, int p2, FILE * inputF);
tree * buildAdjList(int a[][100], int n);
void printAdjArray(tree * adjArr[], int n);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

int a[100][100];
int n,*q;
FILE * inputFile;
int entries, i;
inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
int p1, p2 =0;
if(inputFile==NULL){
    printf("File failed to open.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &entries);
tree * adjarray[entries];
q = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
adjacencyMatrix(a,entries,p1,p2,inputFile);
adjarray[0] = buildAdjList(a, entries);
printAdjArray(adjarray, entries);
return 0;
}

void adjacencyMatrix(int a[][100], int n, int p1, int p2, FILE * inputF){
int i,j;
do{
    for(i = 0;i <= n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j <=n; j++)
        {   if(i==p1 && j == p2){
                 a[i][j] = 1;
                 a[j][i] = 1;
            }
        }
        a[i][i] = 0;
    }
}while(fscanf(inputF, "%d %d", &p1, &p2) !=EOF);
    printArray(a,n);
}
```

Any and all help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your build:

```
tree * buildAdjList(int a[][100], int n)
{       int i, j, k;
    tree *node;
    tree * adjArray[n];
    // work
    return adjArray[0];
}
```

You are trying to return memory from a local variable (which loses scope).  In the above code, `tree * adjArray[n]` creates a **local variable** array (in local address space).  Returning the pointer to the head of that array will be invalid after the function leaves.

Usually, when you want to create a list or node, you need to malloc such that the memory will live in the heap (and therefore will out-live the create function itself).  Something like:

```
tree * buildAdjList(int a[][100], int n)
{
    tree *newtree = malloc(n * sizeof(tree *));
    // work
    return newtree;
}
```

Note that you're malloc-ing a contiguous memory block (read: array) of `tree *`'s and not full `trees`.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this was an old question but I immediately saw a problem in the way you are doing the loop counters. Since this is C++, the elements in an array of size n are arr[0], arr[1], ... arr[n-1]. Your code references arr[n] which is beyond the bounds of the array and can cause a crash.

Your looping logic needs to look like the following so that it does not include i=n in the iterations, by using < instead of <= in the for loop test:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    adjArray[i] = NULL;
```